# Read file from sharepoint 2013 layouts folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file, layouts, read

I want to get the path of a file from `_layouts` folder in SharePoint 2013, for a stream input.

I tried:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4); 
var path = Server.MapPath(@"\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\wfcourrierdep\images\LettreI.png");
var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
doc.Open();
```

And

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
var path = SPUtility.GetCurrentGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\wfcourrierdep\pdf\Dictionnaire.pdf");
var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
doc.Open();
```

No result

I want to use the `GetCurrentGenericSetupPath` or `GetVersionedGenericSetupPath` but I don't know what is the format of my URL I should pass in.

Comment: Are you trying this from a WebPart?

Comment: no from an application page

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as below

```
 var path = SPUtility.GetCurrentGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\wfcourrierdep\pdf\Dictionnaire.pdf");
```

Comment: this is what i made

Comment: Try to output the path and check it is having the correct value. What exception/error you are getting